# npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600, unable to install cordova in windows8

Tags: node.js, cordova, proxy, netbeans-8

I tried to install cordova on my windows8 machine by using the below command in command prompt

```
npm install -g cordova
```

but i'm not able to install because of the following error can any one help me out please.

Error:

> npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600 npm ERR! argv "C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs
>   \node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova" npm
>   ERR! node v0.12.1 npm ERR! npm  v2.5.1 npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
>
> npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established,
>   cause=getaddrinfo EN OTFOUND proxy npm ERR! network This is most
>   likely not a problem with npm itself npm ERR! network and is related
>   to network connectivity. npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind
>   a proxy or have bad network settin gs. npm ERR! network npm ERR!
>   network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the npm ERR!
>   network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\miracle\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Steps you should do:

1. npm cache clean

2.Bring back the node version to v0.10.36 as suggested that the latest version of node may not be compatible for the new cli for window users.

3.Run the node cli or cmd in admin mode

4.npm install -g cordova

Comment: i have my node version with v0.12.1 do i need to uninstall node latest version

Comment: i tried by re installing node v0.10.36 but it through error:

Comment: npm ERR! network tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo EN
OTFOUND
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.

Comment: npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settin
gs.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nod
ejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "cordova"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Windows\System32
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.36
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.28

Comment: npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Windows\System32\npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0

Comment: the above is the error which i get after re installing node.js with v0.10.36

Answer (score 1):

I'm using node:0.12.5, npm:2.12.0. I got the same problem, and my simple solution was just use this command:

```
npm cache clean
```

and then use the installation command for your package, in this case

```
npm install -g cordova
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
npm config set proxy=http://127.0.0.1:8087

npm config set registry=http://registry.npmjs.org
```

*127.0.0.1:8087* is my proxy and proxy port,you should take place of youselves.